# How to add x days to current time and then get days, hours, minutes from the calculated time

Tags: java

Here's my code, but the result is different than expected. It shows 14 days instead of 30, I want it to show days,hours, minutes remaining until time >= System.currentTimeMillis() (until the calculated timestamp is higher or same as current time in milliseconds)

```
int time = (int)System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60); //current Time + 30 days

int day = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(time);
int hour = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(time) - (day * 24);
int min = (int) ((int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time) - (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(time) * 60));
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: I do not see any problem in the code, I've posted all code required to reproduce the issue

Comment: What is `Timestamp` and why are you not doing anything with `stamp`? What do you mean by "calc back days, hours and minutes"? And why do you use `TimeUnit` for a unix timestamp? Please add the MCVE to make it clear what the input is you have, what the result is you currently get and the result you want instead. Somehow you are mixing unix timestamps with time duration.

Comment: Oh, Timestamp wasn't supposed to be in the code, updated. I've explained what result I got and what result I want in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are various things going wrong here.

```
int time = (int)System.currentTimeMillis() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

In this line you're adding minutes to milliseconds. (30 for days, 24 for hours, 60 for minutes, and 60 for seconds).

Furthermore you're casting everything to a int, while the function is returning a long. At the moment of speaking the value which this function should return is: 1580097230808 (it is returning the time since epoch in **milliseconds**).

The max value of a int is 2,147,483,647 which is smaller than 1.580.097.230.808, so that will basically cause a overflow (it will overflow multiple times).

Also the value which needs to be added to the time variable (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) should be casted to a long first, because it is to large for a int.

So when we do all these steps, this will result in the following code:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((long) 30*24*60*60*1000);

System.out.println(time);

int day = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(time);
int hour = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(time) - (day * 24);
int min = (int) ((int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time) - (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(time) * 60));
System.out.println(day);
System.out.println(hour);
System.out.println(min);
```

Which prints the following results:

```
1584393882681 // time in milliseconds since epoch
18337 // number of days since epoch (not the right output)
21 // not the right output
24 // not the right output
```

To get the right output:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((long) 30*24*60*60*1000);

System.out.println(time);

int day = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(time - currentTime);
int hour = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(time - currentTime);
int min = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time - currentTime);
System.out.println(day);
System.out.println(hour);
System.out.println(min);
```

prints:

```
1584394180556 // time since epoch in milliseconds
30 // days left
720 // hours left
43200 // minutes left
```

So for the last functions you need to give them a time in milliseconds, so you don't have to do any conversion yourself. Basically we did the timestamp we calculated minus the current time, and these functions will calculate the days, hours and minutes based on value (time - currentTime).